# Replace 11th Character in each row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an automatically updating MySQL Database with now around 950 Rows. Problem is that I misconfigured the values that my site inserts, so now each row has `Y-m-d-H:i:s` instead of `Y-m-d H:i:s` in the timestamp column. All the timestamps have the same length, so the mistake is always the 11th Character. What mysql query do I need to replace the -?

Comment: What mysql queries have you tried so far?

Comment: Update the post with your code.

Comment: What type is this column? Is it a varchar?

Comment: The table consists of 15 columns, the timestamp column is an Varchar(20) if that helps. I have started using mysql just recently.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @Mureinik Commented that

Comment: `{"tstamp":"2018-01-23-11:41:50","BTC\/USDT":"10301.00000009","ADA\/USDT":"0.53710001","BCC\/USDT":"1535.38293889","BTG\/USDT":"181.22283648","DASH\/USDT":"707.65","ETC\/USDT":"27.3","ETH\/USDT":"941.04750028","LTC\/USDT":"168.5","NEO\/USDT":"111.01201188","NXT\/USDT":"0.33495253","OMG\/USDT":"14.8","XMR\/USDT":"298.05100003","XRP\/USDT":"1.23803043","XVG\/USDT":"0.08800095","ZEC\/USDT":"420"},`

Comment: I want to remove the third - in the timestamp @Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`insert()` *function*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert):

```
update t
    set col = insert(col, 11, 1, ' ');
```

Note:  You should be storing date/time values using native data types, not strings.  But, if you have to use strings, then your format is at least the best string format for such values.